# Command which uses brackets automatically when applied to more symbols

Tags: macros

How can I define a command like *, similar to

```
\newcommand{\astcommand}[1]{{#1}^*}
```

but which, when applied to a single symbol a, gives the output a*, and when applied to multiple symbols, like abc, automatically adds brackets to the output, like (abc)*?

I mean, without having to call it with brackets, as in

```
\astcommand{(abc)}
```

just

```
\astcommand{abc}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version with a *-variant that uses `\mleft` and `\mright` or an optional argument for manually sizing the parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% pass control to an inner function
\NewDocumentCommand{\astcommand}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \cstoica_astcommand_auto:n { #3 } }
   { \cstoica_astcommand_manual:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

% *-version: we want to use \mleft(...\mright)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cstoica_astcommand_auto:n #1
 {
  \_cstoica_astcommand:nnn { \mleft( } { #1 } { \mright) }
 }

% normal version; #1 is either empty or \big, \Big, ...
\cs_new_protected:Npn \cstoica_astcommand_manual:nn #1 #2
 {
  \_cstoica_astcommand:nnn { \mathopen{#1(} } { #2 } { \mathclose{#1)} }
 }

% #1 is the left delimiter, #2 is the string, #3 is the right delimiter
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_cstoica_astcommand:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \tl_count:n { #2 } }
   {% only one token, no fences
    {1}{ #2^{*} }
   }
   { #1 #2 #3^{*} } % more than one token
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\astcommand{a}\quad
 \astcommand{ab}\quad
 \astcommand{\sqrt{a}}\quad
 \astcommand{}$

$\astcommand[\big]{a}\quad\astcommand[\big]{ab}$

$\displaystyle\astcommand*{\frac{a}{b}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

***Caveat*** An input such as `\astcommand{{abc}}` will result in no parentheses. To force parentheses, add an empty group like in

```
\astcommand{{}a}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution using the [`xstring`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xstring) package

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\astcommand}[1]{%
\StrLen{#1}[\mylength]%
\ifnum\mylength>1%
    (#1)^*%
\else%
    #1^*%
\fi}
\begin{document}

$\astcommand{a}$

$\astcommand{b}$

$\astcommand{abc}$

\end{document}
```

If you're likely to need the parenthesis to grow according to the argument, you might like to use `\left` and `\right` or look at the [mleftright](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/oberdiek/mleftright.pdf) package.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice! Do you have any suggestion of how I could use it with for example $\astcommand{\tilde{a}}$, and $\astcommand{\sqrt{a}}$?

Comment: @CristiStoica looks like egreg beat me to it :) glad you have a solution!

Comment: Voted for this options because whilst not as comprehensive it was the better solution for my use case,which was very similar to the original question.